OpenAPI - Scalar - Parameters not showing
I am trying to add Scalar to my C# Web API project, but I have run into a problem where by the parameters are not listing.
Based on this article from Microsoft, the built-in Open API support generates these based on the [FromForm] attributes.
My method signature looks like this:
public async Task<IActionResult> SendFile(IFormFile uploadedFile, [FromForm] string? password)

Now Swagger displays these as I'd expect.

However Scalar does not as thinks the body is some JSON. What is causing this, is it a bug with Scalar?

Below is what I would expect Scalar to display:

It looks like the JSON generated between the two differs slightly. The OpenAPI adds "allOf" to the JSON, the Swagger one does not, what is allOf, is it the cause of the problem? How do I get rid of it?
I could probably write a transformer to go through and add them but that feels very hacky and wrong.

After testing it in my local and also check the github issue, I found it's a known issue for Scalar.
For more details, we can check this link form parameters are not added to the request #3222.

Ah, thanks for this Jason, will keep an eye out for a fix!

@RyanThomas Sure, I also will monitor this issue  with you, and update it once the issue will be fixed.
